# ¿Como se dice ""History-making" en español?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término

I believe "that will make history" would be

> que hará historia

and "that is making" is

> que está haciendo historia.

Is "History-making" a phrase that would make sense in Spanish?

Like "History-making pole vault."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't relate to any word being used as an adjective for some person, event or action that is going to be a history-making person/event/action. However, you could use the sentence *que hace historia* as you stated in your examples: *un salto con pértiga que hará historia*.

In addition, although *hacer historia* makes total sense, for your first example you could also use *pasará a la historia*, which would be it is something which is going to be remembered. Be careful though, as using the verb *pasar* could also be understood as it hasn't got a great importance and is just becoming part of the past or just doesn't have any future. Depends on the context. As for your example, used in the same way as "que hará historia", *un salto con pértiga que **pasará** a la historia*.